# Estimating gamma parameter for exponential data transformation

Tags: r

I'm working on data transformation in order to obtain normality. The exponential transformation (manly, 1974) is known to work for skew,unimodal data (e.g.  chi squared). The transformation is given by
*y=(exp(gamma*x)-1)/(gamma)*

I've written the following code in R to make this work (where I used the formula for gamma proposed by manly)

```
exponential <- function(x,gamma){
  l= length(x)
  y=rep(0,l)
  for (i in 1:l){
    y[i]= (exp(gamma*x[i])-1)/(gamma)
  }
  return(y) 
  }
rmomentcalc <- function(x,r){
  l=length(x)
  mean=mean(x)
  tempmom=0
  for (i in 1:l){
   tempmom=tempmom + (x[i]- mean)^r
  }
  rmom= tempmom/l
  return(rmom)
  }

gammacalc <- function(x){
  mean=mean(x)
  gamma=(2*rmomentcalc(x,3))/(3*((rmomentcalc(x,2)^2))-rmomentcalc(x,4))
  return(gamma)
}
x= rchisq(100,5)
gamma=gammacalc(x)

y=exponential(x,gamma)
shapiro.test(y)
plot(density(y))
```

But this never returns a normal distribution and I really don't know what's wrong.

Comment: So what are you asking about? Your code or the method? If the code, make it more clear exactly what you expect to happen. If your question is about the transformation, then you should be asking on [stats.se] where statistical questions are on-topic.

Comment: It's actually about both, this code doesnt error or anything but it just doesn't give the result it should and I don't know why. There may be another method, but I don't know which one.. I'll ask it there thanks!